# Calculate the Legendre symbol of two integers in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, what formula may I write in a cell to calculate the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) of an integer `a` and a prime `p`, defined by

[image: Legendre symbol definition from wikipedia]
(picture taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol))

Comment: White text on a very light gray background is a very bad idea :-)

Comment: @Dominique The background is dark grey for me, was not aware this was different for others.

Comment: Don't mind the colours. It's always better describing text as text instead of working with images. It looks like you might need an `=IF(...,1, 0)` construction. In case it might be too difficult, you might need to write an UDF (User-Defined Function) but in order to be sure, we need to be able to read the requirements.

Comment: @Dominique Also see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) for the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a Visual Basic for Applications function to deal with this:

```
Function LEGENDRESYMBOL(a As Long, p As Long) As Long
    If p = 2 Or ISPRIMETRIALDIVISION(p) = False Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1000, , "The given denominator of the Legendre symbol was not an odd prime."
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    If a >= p Then ' (a/p) = (b/p) for a congruent to b mod p
        LEGENDRESYMBOL = LEGENDRESYMBOL(a Mod p, p)
        Exit Function
    
    ElseIf a < 0 Then ' Exploit multiplicity of the Legendre symbol and knowledge of what (-1/p) is
        Dim legendreMinusOne As Long
        If p Mod 4 = 1 Then
            legendreMinusOne = 1
        Else
            legendreMinusOne = -1
        End If
        
        LEGENDRESYMBOL = legendreMinusOne * LEGENDRESYMBOL(-a, p)
        Exit Function
    ElseIf a = 0 Then
        LEGENDRESYMBOL = 0
        Exit Function
    ElseIf a = 1 Then ' 1 is always a square mod p
        LEGENDRESYMBOL = 1
        Exit Function
    ElseIf a Mod 2 = 0 Then ' Handle multiples of 2 in a special case since how we will soon use quadratic reciprocity
        Dim legendreTwo As Long
        If p Mod 8 = 1 Or p Mod 8 = 7 Then
            legendreTwo = 1
        Else
            legendreTwo = -1
        End If
        LEGENDRESYMBOL = legendreTwo * LEGENDRESYMBOL(a / 2, p)
        Exit Function
    
    ElseIf ISPRIMETRIALDIVISION(a) Then ' a is prime so use quadratic reciprocity
        Dim quadraticReciprocityExponent As Long
        quadraticReciprocityExponent = (a - 1) * (p - 1) / 4
        
        Dim flippedLegendre As Long
        flippedLegendre = LEGENDRESYMBOL(p, a) ' inductively, well be able to work this out, a is smaller than p so eventually hit a base case.
        
        If quadraticReciprocityExponent Mod 2 = 0 Then
            LEGENDRESYMBOL = flippedLegendre
        Else
            LEGENDRESYMBOL = -flippedLegendre
        End If
        Exit Function
        
    Else ' a is a composite number not handled by any of our other previous cases. split a into its prime factors and exploit multiplicative nature of legendre symbol.
    
        Dim legendreProduct As Long
        legendreProduct = 1
        Dim primeFactors() As Long
        primeFactors = PRIMEFACTORSWITHMULTIPLICITY(a)

        ' Loop through the prime factors
        For Each factor In primeFactors
            legendreProduct = legendreProduct * LEGENDRESYMBOL(CLng(factor), p)
        Next factor
        
        LEGENDRESYMBOL = legendreProduct
        Exit Function
        
    End If
    
    
End Function
```

where `ISPRIMETRIALDIVISION` returns a Boolean value corresponding to whether or not its input is prime, and `PRIMEFACTORSWITHMULTIPLICITY` returns all the prime factors of the given input with multiplicity.

Answer (score -1):

First, I'd like to show the problematic picture in a more readable form. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to edit the original post.
[image: Legendre]

The symbols used are not typical, so it is difficult to transform it into simple text.
Taking into account the Euler's criterion [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol), the following LAMBDA function can be proposed:

```
LEGENDRE(a,p) : =LAMBDA(a,p, IF(MOD(a,p)=0, 0, IF(MOD(a^((p-1)/2),p)=1, 1, -1)))
```

Comment: According to this URL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) you need a loop in order to check whether a number is a quadratic residu or not. This means that you can only use this in Excel, writing an UDF (User-Defined Function): you need to loop over all possible values of `x`, checking whether `x^2 mod p =a`. In other words, VBA is a must for solving this problem.